# SockPathMode - what is it?

Tags: macos, network, launchd

I have a plist installed on my system with the following in it:

```
<dict>
  <key>SockPathMode</key>
  <integer>438</integer>
```

`man launchd.plist` tells me:

```
SockPathMode <integer>
This optional key specifies the mode of the socket.
```

I haven't been able to find a list of modes and I haven't heard of 438 different modes either! If anyone can shed some light on what this key and value is really about I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The integer in the key *SockPathMode* is the decimal presentation of the octal POSIX permissions of the UNIX socket.

[Converter](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/decimal-to-octal.html): 438 > 0666 > file permissions: rw-rw-rw- (owner, group and anyone is allowed to read and write from/to the socket.

Comment: Ahhh, got it. Thanks. Did you find that written down somewhere or has converting numbers to file permissions become second nature? :)